# Edit HTML Page in Browser

Tags: html, editing

I have a html page on work team site intranet page, hosted on a server which doesn't support PHP. It is a simple page with some text and a table, and I want to make it editable, i.e. so that anyone could edit and save it from their browser.
 Is it possible to do in my case? 
Thanks.

Comment: without a server side language, all the modifications cannot be saved permanently

Answer (score 1):

If you only have static page hosting (i.e. no server-side processing like PHP or ASP), then no, you cannot make a file editable from a web browser.

Comment: The server DOES support ASP. Is it possible then?

Comment: Sure, but you'll have to either write your own file editor in ASP code, or find an existing piece of software written in ASP that does that.

Comment: Any things you have in mind in particular? I don't need anything too fancy, just a simple "double click to edit" feature.

Comment: Nothing I know of; ASP is not a very popular language and not one I'm particularly familiar with. A quick google "asp file editor" didn't turn up anything that looked particularly useful, but you can do some more googling yourself.

Comment: Ok I will have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a page needs atleast a **database** and a **programming language** like **PHP**. If either of these are not present on the server it is not possible to keep track of changes made to the content of your page or to render the html with content from the database.